# Is there an antonym to "atom" and "atomic"?

Tags: word-request

Is there an antonym to "atom"? The only thing that comes to mind is "group of atoms", because that's literally what the antonym of "atom" should be, but that's a phrase. Is there any word for it? Also, the same thing with "atomic", the closest thing I can come up with is "relating to a group of atoms".

Comment: Antonym means the opposite of something, like small versus large. atom has no opposite. So I really cannot understand at all what you mean....Not every object has an antonym. What an odd idea....

Comment: Can you explain the context and why you (think you) need an antonym for “atom”?

Comment: Are you sure ‘antonym’ means what you think it means? Perhaps look it up in a dictionary, and define it in the question.

Comment: The word "atomic" in the sense of "indivisible" has antonyms, such as "compound", but you don't seems to be asking about antonyms of that sense.

Answer (score 3):

**The antonym of *atomic* (in the sense of *atomic bomb*) is *non-atomic*.**

*Atom* has no meaningful antonym because a "non-atom" could refer to an electron or an eggplant or an elephant. **There is no name for the set of objects that are not atoms.**

This Quora post may interest you: [Do nouns have antonyms?](https://www.quora.com/Do-nouns-have-antonyms)

Comment: Weapons that are not atomic (or nuclear) are often called "conventional" in discussions about military history, politics, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I should have thought of that, because My Chemical Romance has a series of releases titled Conventional Weapons and each cover features a different non-atomic weapon.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an "antonym" for "atomic". Why would you need one? It is like asking *what is the opposite of a zebra*? A non-zebra? Obviously, there is no such thing - either something *is* or *is not* a zebra. Likewise with atoms.

Something that is atomic is *related to atoms*. Of course, everything in the physical universe is comprised of atoms! But not everything is *about* atoms. When we say that something is "atomic" we mean that it operates *at an atomic level*. For example, an atomic bomb works by harnessing the power of atoms. Arguably *all* explosive material is harnessing the energy within matter, but an atomic bomb *directly* access the energy held at that level.

Because atoms are a "level" of the composition of matter, some things are termed "sub-atomic" if they operate at a level *below* atoms (for example *electrons* are sub-atomic particles) and "super-atomic" if they operate at a level *above* atoms.

"Groups of atoms" as you mention could be a number of things. For example, if you are talking about a base element like gold, it is comprised entirely of the same atoms - atoms of gold. You wouldn't say "a group of gold atoms", you would just refer to it as a quantity of gold. As I'm sure you know, elements combine to form *compounds* - for example, one atom of hydrogen and two atoms of oxygen make water. The smallest unit of a compound is a *molecule*, which in the case of water would be 3 atoms but in other compounds, it could be as little as 2.

Really though, if you are not speaking about atoms as a *level* of a physical model, there is no need for an antonym.

Answer (score 1):

Originally "atomic" meant that something could be divided into small, indivisible units. In this sense the antonym might be "continuous".

Comment: The antonym of *continuous* is usually given as *discrete*, but you might be on to something.

Comment: I like this answer, but I think the definition needs correction.